# How can I identify which variable, from a couple, is the independent one?

Tags: python, pandas, static

I'll try to explain the problem. I'm studying the correlation of a bunch of process variables with the model error (the model is an ecuation that regulates part of manufacturing process). My problem is that I have two high correlated variables with very similar correlation values. When I study correlation between both I, obviously , obtain very high values too. 
My question is: 
Which one is the independent one? It's so important its identification.
Thanks.

Comment: hi @pablo-ferngon, please provide a MVCE

Comment: @AndyK do you know about the `[MCVE]` shortcut? It automatically creates a link to the documentation. Like so: [MCVE].

Comment: Hi @IanS oh wow. thanks! (awesome, feels like magic!)

Comment: @pablo-ferngon, please provide a [MCVE]